# java jdbc проблема

Tags: java

Выводит error in smth, помогите

```
try {
    Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
    final String query = "query верный";
    ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery(query);
    result.next();
} catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("error in smth");
}
```

Comment: Выведите Exception который возникает.  exc.printStackTrace(), там будет видно на что ругается.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: Выдало это, погуглил ошибку и исправил, но выдает теперь это
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to ResultSet
```ResultSet result = stat.executeUpdate(query);```

Comment: Исправил ```int result = ...```